# Java - Play2 Are Actors required for WebSockets implementation?

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0

I am trying to implement a WebSockets based solution with Play2 and Java. Currently I'm not using [Actor Model](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAkka) for concurrency management. Instead, it's just [handling the WebSockets using callbacks](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-using-callbacks).

The problem is the server is unable to 'broadcast' the messages across to multiple clients. For example, I need all the active browser sessions to receive a simple notification after an action is triggered through a client. Instead, I'm just able to simulate this for a single client session. In effect, it just acts as a regular Ajax request/response scenario.

My guess is the WebSockets solution with Play2 & Java with simple callbacks isn't able to broadcast the messages to all of the connected client browsers.

**Callback server code**

```
public static WebSocket<String> heartUpdate() {
        return new WebSocket<String>() {
            public void onReady(final WebSocket.In<String> in,
                    WebSocket.Out<String> out) {
                in.onMessage(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void invoke(String event) throws Throwable {
                        Product product = Product.find.byId(Long.decode(event));
                        // Other business stuff
                        out.write(entity.id + " " + decimalValue);
                    }
                });
                in.onClose(new Callback0() {
                    @Override
                    public void invoke() throws Throwable {

                    }
                });
                out.write(DELIM_USERID_REP);
            }
        };
    }
```

**Routes entry**

```
GET /repsocket   controllers.Application.heartUpdate
```

**Client side**

```
<script>
    // Onto the WebSockets now
    var WS = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket;
    var socket = new WS("@routes.Application.heartUpdate.webSocketURL(request)");

    var receiveEvent = function(event) {
        alert(event.data);
        // Notification badge visible with a common text
        $('#notify').text(event.data);
        $('#notify').addClass('visible');
    }
        $('#heart').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.send(@product.id);
        });
    socket.onmessage = receiveEvent;
    </script>
```

In the above case, the action triggering client is the one that successfully receives the message from the server, while any other browser sessions do not.

I failed to find any documentation aligned with Play2 with Java & WebSockets that suggests a mandatory use of Actors to maintain a consistent communication with all connected active clients.

**Question:** Should WebSockets in Play2 with Java be implemented with Actor Model to broadcast the message to all active client sessions?

**Edit:**
The screenshot below reflects the 2 states of browsers to which I have logged in to using 2 valid user credentials.

Ideally, WebSockets' response from the server should create the same notification badges on both the browsers.

[image]

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: @nikpon No errors, the message from the server is just reflected in 1 browser session - that triggered the request & not in any other connected client sessions

Comment: how did you get a session of the browser?

Comment: @nikpon logged-on to the system using 2 browsers with valid user credentials. Please refer to the edit.

Comment: For the clear experiment better use the browsers of the same manufacturer like FF e.g.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the code you posted, it seems the problem is that you are not saving a reference to each connection, so you can later broadcast messages. Something like this:

```
// Just an example: does not deal with concurrency problems
private static final Set<WebSocket.Out<String>> SOCKETS = new HashSet<>();

public static WebSocket<String> heartUpdate() {
    return new WebSocket<String>() {
        public void onReady(final WebSocket.In<String> in,
                    final WebSocket.Out<String> out) {
            SOCKETS.add(out);
            in.onMessage(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void invoke(String event) throws Throwable {
                    for(WebSocket.Out<String> s: SOCKETS) {
                        s.write("SOME MESSAGE");    
                    }
                }
            });
            in.onClose(new Callback0() {
                @Override
                public void invoke() throws Throwable {
                    SOCKETS.remove(out);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

You can also use actors to model this problem: having an actor responsible to keep track of the connections and to deal with new sockets connection/close.

If you want to use Akka there are [some activator templates](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/templates#filter:websocket) to get you started.